# Shouldn't __metaclass__ force the use of a metaclass in Python?

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, metaclass

I've been trying to learn about metaclasses in Python. I get the main idea, but I can't seem to activate the mechanism. As I understand it, you can specify M to be as the metaclass when constructing a class K by setting `__metaclass__` to M at the global or class level. To test this out, I wrote the following program:

```
p = print

class M(type):
    def __init__(*args):
        type.__init__(*args)
        print("The rain in Spain")

p(1)
class ClassMeta:
    __metaclass__ = M

p(2)
__metaclass__ = M
class GlobalMeta: pass

p(3)
M('NotMeta2', (), {})

p(4)
```

However, when I run it, I get the following output:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Daniel Wong\Desktop>python --version
Python 3.0.1

C:\Documents and Settings\Daniel Wong\Desktop>python meta.py
1
2
3
The rain in Spain
4
```

Shouldn't I see "The rain in Spain" after 1 and 2? What's going on here?

Comment: The double negative "doesn't ... not force" is hard to parse.  Could you fix the question, please?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think it should be easier to understand now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Python 3 (which you are using) metaclasses are specified by a keyword parameter in the class definition:

```
class ClassMeta(metaclass=M):
  pass
```

Specifying a `__metaclass__` class property or global variable is old syntax from Python 2.x and not longer supported. See also ["What's new in Python 3"](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax) and [PEP 2115](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/).

Answer (score 2):

This works as you expect in Python 2.6 (and earlier), but in 3.0 metaclasses are specified differently:

```
class ArgMeta(metaclass=M): ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of metaclasses has [changed](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html) in Python 3.0.  The `__metaclass__` attribute is no longer special at either the class nor the module level.  To do what you're trying to do, you need to specify `metaclass` as a keyword argument to the `class` statement:

```
p = print

class M(type):
    def __init__(*args):
        type.__init__(*args)
        print("The rain in Spain")

p(1)
class ClassMeta(metaclass=M): pass
```

Yields:

```
1
The rain in Spain
```

As you'd expect.