# Unexpected: flufl.enum prints integer value

Tags: python, enums

Using Python 3, I unpackaged the flufl.enum code into my application source tree just to try it.  Sample code:

```
from taurine.flufl.enum import Enum

class Colors(Enum):
    red = 1
    green = 2
    blue = 3

print(Colors.red)
red = Colors.red
print("red == Colors.red "+str(red == Colors.red))
print("red == Colors.blue "+str(red == Colors.blue))
print("red is Colors.red "+str(red is Colors.red))
```

Everything works as expected except the print(Color.red).  According to http://packages.python.org/flufl.enum/docs/using.html I'd expect it to print "Colors.red" but it's printing 1.  Anyone familiar with this package know if there's a way to get it to print "Colors.red"?  I've posted a question on the library's site but thought someone here might have experience as well.

EDIT: It does work as expected if I define Colors with:

```
Colors = make_enum('Colors','red green blue')
```

But I prefer the syntax of:

```
class Colors(Enum):
    red = 1
    green = 2
    blue = 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized init wasn't even being called on EnumMetaclass.  I think the following code in _enum.py is meant to make inheriting from Enum all you'd need to do, but something about it doesn't work and it's beyond me:

```
class Enum:
    __metaclass__ = EnumMetaclass
```

This works:

```
class Colors(metaclass=EnumMetaclass):
    red = 1
    green = 2
    blue = 3
```

I'm happy now.

EDIT: Found out why.  See the first answer to the following question: [Shouldn't __metaclass__ force the use of a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818483/shouldnt-metaclass-force-the-use-of-a-metaclass-in-python)

Comment: Hmm.  Python 3 should probably have a warning for when the \_\_metaclass\_\_ attribute appears in a class definition.

Comment: Agreed, that would have clued me in more quickly.